# Bandwidth of the Derivative of a Message

Tags: continuous-signals, bandwidth

If I have a message signal $m(t)$ and it has a bandwidth $B$. I know that the bandwidth of $m^N(t)$ is $NB$. But what is the bandwidth of $\frac{d m(t)}{dt}$?
Thanks!

Comment: @MBaz: This is about the bandwidth, not about the magnitude.

Comment: @MattL. Thanks for pointing it out -- I misread the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Checking a table of Fourier transform properties you'll find that the Fourier transform of the derivative is given by

$$\mathcal{F}\left\{\frac{dm(t)}{dt}\right\}=j\omega M(\omega)\tag{1}$$

where $M(\omega)$ is the Fourier transform of $m(t)$. Now if $M(\omega)$ is band-limited, what does this tell you about the Fourier transform of $dm(t)/dt$?

Comment: Would it be the same? Since the $jw$ would only affect the amplitude of the signal?

Comment: @Neilerino: Well, if $M(\omega)=0$ for a certain frequency range, then $j\omega M(\omega)$ must be zero too, right?

Comment: Yes! Therefore the bandwidth would be the same as $m(t)$.